# How to change redirect route for unverified user in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have multiple login `user`,`admin`, and `client`. Authentication is working fine for all users. But I have problem to redirect them to different route when their login session ends, or if they try to access pages without logging in. All of them is redirected to `login` route.

I know that redirect route is configured in `Middleware/Authenticate.php`. But I don't know how to modify it to work as I wanted.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
      protected function redirectTo($request)
      {
         if ($this_is_an_admin){ // How to manage this?
            return route('admin/login');
         }
         elseif ($this_is_a_client){ // How to manage this?
            return route('client/login');
         }
         else {
            return route('login');         
         }
      }
}
```

So how can I assign different route for each user, for example `user` goes to `user/login`, `admin` goes to `admin/login` and `client` goes to `client/login`.

Comment: Your middleware needs to run after the initialisation of the StartSession middleware, better after the web middleware group.

Answer (score 0):

When a user is signed out, you don't know who is the current user in the session. Therefore, you **cannot** switch to different routes based on the current user.

One possible solution is storing the last user role (admins, client or user) in the cookie and use that value in your middleware. Of course, you have to set the cookie everytime users sign in successfully or via another middleware that adds the cookie after every authenticated response.

You also should have links to allow users to switch between different sign-in forms for different roles in your UI.